# Trying to join a MYSQL table with a conditional join

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am trying to join a table in MYSQL, but based on a condition.

I have a checks table, and each check can be assigned to EITHER a user, a department/location combination, so could be a location on its own or a location and a department.

**Checks table:**

```
+----------+---------------+------------+------------+--------+----------+
| check_id | check_type_id |    due     | created_by | status | sign_off |
+----------+---------------+------------+------------+--------+----------+
|    19335 |            43 | 18/09/2017 |          3 |      1 |        1 |
|    19336 |             4 | 19/09/2017 |          3 |      1 |        1 |
|    19357 |            62 | 21/09/2017 |      47336 |      1 |        1 |
+----------+---------------+------------+------------+--------+----------+
```

Users assignments are stored in an check_assigned_users table, so I can join this fine.

BUT departments and locations are stored in the same table check_assigned_areas.

**Check assigned area table:**

```
+------------------------+---------------+----------+
| check_assigned_area_id | check_area_id | check_id |
+------------------------+---------------+----------+
|                  18801 |             9 |    19335 |
|                  18802 |           816 |    19336 |
|                  18803 |           816 |    19336 |
|                  18804 |          8086 |    19336 |
|                  18835 |          8091 |    19357 |
+------------------------+---------------+----------+
```

So i need some way of joining the areas table based on the area_level (3=location and 4=department) to get the location or department name.

**Areas table:**

```
+---------+------------+--------------+------------+--------+
| area_id | area_title |  area_name   | area_level | active |
+---------+------------+--------------+------------+--------+
|    8091 | Location   | Luton Office |          3 |      1 |
|    8092 | Department | Development  |          4 |      1 |
+---------+------------+--------------+------------+--------+
```

So my thought process would be:

1) Join the check_assigned_areas table on checks by check_id

2) Join areas once for locations, and again for departments based on the area_level.

Like this:

```
LEFT JOIN `areas` `l` ON `l`.`area_id` = `a`.`check_area_id` AND `l`.`area_level` = '3'
LEFT JOIN `areas` `d` ON `d`.`area_id` = `a`.`check_area_id` AND `l`.`area_level` = '4'
```

But it just doesn't seem to produce any results

I've been trying many variations of the below query, but I either get no data at all returned, or duplicates:

```
SELECT `c`.*, `t`.`check_name`,`a`.`check_area_id`,`l`.`area_name` AS 'location_name', `d`.`area_name` AS 'dept_name'
FROM `checks` `c`
LEFT JOIN `check_assigned_areas` `a` ON `a`.`check_id` = `c`.`check_id`
LEFT JOIN `areas` `l` ON `l`.`area_id` = `a`.`check_area_id` AND `l`.`area_level` = '3'
LEFT JOIN `areas` `d` ON `d`.`area_id` = `a`.`check_area_id` AND `l`.`area_level` = '4'
LEFT JOIN `check_types` `t` ON `t`.`check_type_id` = `c`.`check_type_id`
WHERE `c`.`org_id` = '297'
AND `c`.`status` != '0'
AND `c`.`due` <= '2017-09-21'
```

I've been reading a lot about conditional joins and generally the feeling I get is that its not the right way to do things.

So my question is, can I get this query to do what I want or do I need to restructure my database to have a check_assigned_departments and check_assigned_locations table, which seems overkill, i think because they are both stored in the areas table, so I think there must be a way to join this correctly, but after 3 days of trying I'm at a loss?

SQL Fiddle of the schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3c41/1

As you can see in the fiddle, check_id 19358 has 2 assignments(area_id's) in the check_assigned_areas table, 8091 and 8093. 8091 is a location(area_level=3) and 8093 which is a department (area_level=4), so i would expect the result to be in the same column, with the area_name populated in location_name and department_name

This is the result I am expecting:

```
array(13) {
  ["location_name"]=>
  string(9) "Mk Office"
  ["dept_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["check_icon"]=>
  string(9) "fa-bell-o"
  ["check_desc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["check_status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["check_type"]=>
  string(11) "Break Glass"
  ["check_area_id"]=>
  string(4) "8090"
  ["check_user_id"]=>
  string(5) "47336"
  ["due"]=>
  string(10) "2017-09-21"
  ["check_id"]=>
  string(5) "19360"
  ["user_name"]=>
  string(13) "Company Admin"
  ["sort_order"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["linked_documents"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

**EDIT:** added sqlfiddle and result set to question

Comment: if you can provide http://sqlfiddle.com/ and desired result set would be good

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle complains when running the query - table Users doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you want a hierarchy - how do we know which department belongs to which office?

Comment: I do have a hierarchy, but its not relevant to this query surely? The purpose of the question is joining areas based on the area_level

Comment: And I cant add the users table to the fiddle, its saying the request is too large